# JSF ViewScoped beans called 3 times at every request

Tags: jsf, tomcat, primefaces

I have a strange behavior in all of my JSF beans (with View, Request and Custom scopes).

In my `web.xml` the state saving method is set to `client`.

No matter which scope I define in my managed beans, at every GET request the bean constructor is called 3 times. It happens for all views.

As far as I know, a bean is constructed 1 time and put in a scope. Does anybody wonder why JSF is always creating them 3 times before rendering the view?

Running on Mojarra 2.1.13, PrimeFaces 3.5, JDK 1.6.x. and Apache Tomcat 7.0.27 Thanks!

Thanks.

Comment: Post a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) to replicate the problem.

Comment: Sorry Luiggi, but it's a huge project and my company doesn't allow to publish in the web. I can post the entire web.xml or bean declarations. Thanks.

Comment: SSCCE != real production code. Just nail down the problem to the smallest possible amount of code (which you're of course completely free to rename) and then post it here. No need to post a monster web.xml of which perhaps only 1 line is actually relevant the problem.

Comment: Please access to the SSCCE link posted in my last comment. As you can see, the SSCCE is just a **code sample** to replicate the problem, it is not meant to be your current specific code.

Comment: For other hints on how to create an SSCCE, see also http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info

Comment: Yeah, sure, LOL... I'm sorry Luiggi. I did visit before and when I started to create this SSCCE I realize that the problem is in my template because I isolated one page and the problem stop... when I included the page on my template the 3 times construction came back.

Comment: This SSCCE solved the problem because I found out trying to isolate! Thank you all! I'll post my own answer!

Comment: In future create an SSCCE before posting a question. In many cases, it'll help you much better to see and understand the cause of the problem problem and therefore also the solution, as you figured. If not, then you still have a "world class" question to post with the SSCCE ready for use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 2+ other constructions were happening because of a .js and a .css that were been imported but the files were missing.

This

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="#{resource['js/bootstrap-fileupload.js']}?vs=#{serverStartDate.time}"></script>
```

caused 1 construction and `bootstrap-fileupload.css` caused the other. There 2 files were deleted a few days ago and removing the 2 imports solved the problem.